# Select Employee name, Manager name, Max salary of Employee Under each Manager

Tags: sql

[image]

I have the above table, and I want to get Employeename, Manager name, Max salary of Employee Under each manager

Thanks in advance

Comment: Employee name ..manager name??Where is other table??

Comment: Google for tutorials on joining tables

Comment: So, you need one row per each manager, with the data on the employee with the largest salary? For managerId=2 it would be Raja, and for managerId=1 it would be Seetha, right?

Comment: Your desired result can't fit it in a single result set.

Comment: Here name means employee name and based on managerid we need to get manager name

Comment: Suppose take first row id =1 name=raja and managerid=2 so manager name =ravi

Comment: Or can fit, but it will be repetition of data.

Comment: If you have 2 employees under same manager, you will see max salary under a manager twice. Are you really after that?

Comment: if you have 2 employees under same manager then among that two employees i wont display max salary employee name, salary and manager name

Answer (score 0):

```
select name as Employeename,(select t.name from table t where t.id=managerId) as ManagerName,(select max(u.sallary) from table u where u.managerId=managerId) as MaxSalary from table
```

This will give you the expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.name,e.name as managerName,max(b.Salary)
FROM Employee b
JOIN Employee e ON b.Id= e.ManagerId
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from emp
select * from dep
Select top 2 employeename,managerName, MaxSalary  from  (Select  b.Name as employeename,
(select t.Name  from emp t where t.empId=b.managerId ) as managerName,
(select max(u.salary) from emp u where u.depId=b.depid) as MaxSalary
from [Emp] b ) as qq`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).